# How to set up swift in Visual Studio?

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install `swift` in `visual studio code`. I have read every documentation and watched every possible video on the internet.
Do you have any solution for my problem ?

I am attaching a screenshot for more help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a third party product called "Swift for VSCode".

See this link: https://forums.swift.org/t/introducing-swift-for-visual-studio-code/54246